# VFL expression not translating IB constraints as expected

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development and VFL is giving me a huge headache. I am trying to translate the following constraints into VFL for a simple view as a study case but my width is never inferred and unless I explicitly specify a width, the view never shows up.

[image]

```
H:|-50-[v0]-50-|
V:|-20-[v0(100)]
```

As I understand, these expressions should translate to the IB constraints in the image. What am I doing wrong here?

Entire constraints declaration:

```
scrollView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-50-[v0]-50-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": bigFrameUIView]))

scrollView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-20-[v0(100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": bigFrameUIView]))
```

Comment: Are you setting the `contentSize` of your scroll view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For UIScrollView there several rules. You can check them out [here](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/)

But in short, you have to:

- specify only **one** subview for your scrollView and attach it to
  your scrollView sides, so scrollView will use it as content
- set some constraints for size of your added contentView, so it can
  infer    scrollView about contentSize
- place your other elements inside contentView of your scrollView

This code will probably work, if you add this v0 to UIView

Comment: This is correct. I just tried it out and adding another UIView as the content worked, even though I really don't like the idea of stacking 2 views (UIScrollView + contentView) just to be able to build my interface.